# Compound if condition inside list comprehension doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have this code:

```
 jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
 with open(ticket_file, 'r') as f:
     tickets = [word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word) and word not in tickets]
```

`ticket_file` contains this:

```
PRJ1-2333
PRJ1-2333
PRJ1-2333
PRJ2-2333
PRJ2-2333
MISC-5002
```

After the code runs, the `tickets` list contains these:

```
['PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333', 'PRJ2-2333', 'MISC-5002']
```

I expected this:

```
['PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333', 'MISC-5002']
```

Why is `word not in tickets` condition not eliminating duplicates?  The regex filter is working fine, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

- Sets can only contain unique values

  - I've used `set(...)` to be explicit, but `set(...)` can be replace with `{...}`.
  - This implementation builds a generator inside `set()`
  - Don't use a list-comprehension inside (e.g. `set([...])`), because the list can potentially use a lot of memory.
- *word not in tickets* causes `NameError: name 'tickets' is not defined` because, from the perspective of the list comprehension, `tickets` does not exist.

  - If you're not getting a `NameError`, it's because `tickets` exists in memory already, or `tickets` is assigned in your code, but not this example.
  - Given the example code, if you clear the environment, and run the code, you'll get an error.
- `.match` returns something like `<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='PRJ1-2333'>` or `None`

  - Where `match = jira_regex.match(t)`, if there's a match, get the value with `match[0]`.
  - `word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word)` assumes that if `jira_regex.match(word)` isn't `None` that the match is always equal to `word`. Based on the sample data, this is the case, but I don't know if that's the case with the real data.

```py
jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    tickets = set(word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word))
    
print(tickets)

{'MISC-5002', 'PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333'}
```

### Without `.split()`:

- It seems as if `line.split()` is being used to get rid of the newline, which can be accomplished with `line.strip()`

#### Option 1:

```py
jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    tickets = set(jira_regex.match(word.strip())[0] for word in f)  # assumes .match will never be None
    
print(tickets)
{'MISC-5002', 'PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333'}
```

#### Option 2:

```py
jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    tickets = set(word.strip() for word in f if jira_regex.match(word.strip()))
    
print(tickets)
{'MISC-5002', 'PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333'}
```

### For the code to be explicit:

```py
jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
tickets = list()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    
    for t in f:        
        t = t.strip()  # remove space from beginning and end and remove newlines
        match = jira_regex.match(t)  # assign .match to a variable
        if match != None:  # check if a match was found
            match = match[0]  # extract the match value, depending on the data, this may not be the same as 't'
            if match not in tickets:  # check if match is in tickets
                tickets.append(match)  # if match is not in tickets, add it to tickets

print(tickets)
['PRJ1-2333', 'PRJ2-2333', 'MISC-5002']
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is word not in tickets condition not eliminating duplicates?

It is because the variable `tickets` does not exist yet until the list comprehension is finished.

You can do a `set comprehension` like this (not tested):

```
tickets = {word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word)}
```

Comment: How is using a set comprehension, different from my solution?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney you are building the list first from the list comprehension and then passing it to the `set()` function. There is a big overhead if the size of the items is huge.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney reviewed your code again. I think they are not different since you are just passing the the generator instead. I could be wrong. A benchmark can be an answer.

Comment: I used `set()` to be explicit, but as you just noted, I'm not building a list comprehension first.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a difference in coding style I guess. I most of the time use, list, set, and dict comprehensions and generator expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you predefined `tickets` in your code. 
The reason the `if` statement is not working is because although you are adding more and more values into `tickets`, the `tickets` in your `if` statement will always be empty, so `word` is always not in.

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
 jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
 with open(ticket_file, 'r') as f:
     [tickets.append(word) for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word) and word not in tickets]
```

Comment: If _I'm assuming you predefined tickets as an empty list in your code_ is the case, then this will work. However, it's considered anti-pythonic to implement this type of [`side-effect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

Answer (score -1):

Why is **word not in tickets** condition not eliminating duplicates? This is not working because when you are using

```
 tickets = [word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word) and word not in tickets]
```

This is a list comprehension & hence will assign value to variable 'tickets' after reading all content from your file. Hence, in short, the condition, **word not in tickets** is literally adding nothing to the code as 'tickets' won't be assigned until every text is being read. What you can do is

```
 jira_regex = re.compile("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+")
 with open(ticket_file, 'r') as f:
     tickets = [word for line in f for word in line.split() if jira_regex.match(word)]
     tickets=set(tickets)
```

This will remove all your duplicate values

Comment: This is essentially a copy of the first part of my solution, except with worse performance because you're building the entire list first and then using `set()` on the entire list.